# Почему Йорк а не Ёрк?

Tags: правописание

Если пишется "ёж" и "ёлка", то почему "Йорк", а не "Ёрк"? И наоборот.

Comment: Russian orthography is no way _phonetic_, it's _historical-morphological_, so expecting phonetic spellings in Russian is all in vain, bro.

Comment: @йощь Вот здесь (после Вашего вопроса и полученного ответа) есть интересные рассуждения и **подтверждённая информация** по поводу написания слова "Йорк" — в историко-лингвистическом аспекте. https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/463132/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%9d%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%99%d0%be%d1%80%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%8b-1918-%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0 (Как писали «Нью-Йорк» до реформы 1918 года?)

Answer (score 11):

Because Russian transliterations are not consistent.

The letter *ё* didn't make it into Russian before late XVIII century. Church Slavonic language didn't use the sound cluster this letter denotes.

When it came to use, the letter *ё* had replaced the etymological *е* in native Russian words.

English names in *yo, ye* etc. (and names borrowed through English, especially Japanese ones) were traditionally written using *iо, iе* in Russian: *Iоркъ, Нью-Iоркъ, Iорикъ; Iокогама, Iеддо, iенъ* etc, although *йо* was used occasionally as well.

After the orthography reform of 1918, the English names changed the first letter to *й* (*Йорк, Йорик*) while the traditional Japanese ones retained the now uniform *и*: *иена, Иокогама*.

The most widely accepted Japanese to Russian transliteration system calls for using *ё* to denote the respective Japanese sound.

However, the spelling of the words already rooted in Russian is grandfathered.